# WPF,, How to make Datagrid cell Editable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to make datagrid column cell editable so that user can write something and i May get that text in code behind variable. I tried to add textbox it works and provides a extbox in cell but I can not able to get the typed text in variable it is giving null value. I tried the following
In xaml

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Result" Binding="{Binding Result}" Width="10*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterAligned}" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <TextBox Name="datagridTextBox" Style="{StaticResource basicTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

In code behind tried this but not succesfull as it is returning null

```
   for (int i = 0; i < AllTestsDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridRow row = AllTestsDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
  TextBox ele1 = ((ContentPresenter)(AllTestsDataGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row))).Content as TextBox;
string value= ele1.Text;
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On your data grid have this event enabled

```
SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" DataGridCell.Selected="Grid_Selected"
```

Then in code behind do this.

```
        private void Grid_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
            {
                DataGridCell cell = (e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell);
                if (cell.IsReadOnly == true)
                    return;
                // Starts the Edit on the row;
                DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
                grd.BeginEdit(e);
                cell.IsEditing = true;
                string cellValue = GetSelectedCellValue();
            }
        }

        public string GetSelectedCellValue()
        {

            DataGridCellInfo cells = Grid.SelectedCells[0];

            string columnName = cells.Column.SortMemberPath;

            var item = cells.Item;

            if (item == null || columnName == null) return null;

            object result = item.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(item, null);

            if (result == null) return null;

            return result.ToString();
        }
```